# Controller name being lost when trying to post to controller action after file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC Controller which contains a couple of actions. One action is responsible for changing rate. Another one is responsible for uploading a file. 
the actions work correctly when I play with them. but as soon as I upload a file, if I try to change the rate the post action fails because the url it tries to post to lack the controller name in it. Here are the codes. 
here is my code in the view:

Change rate:

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("UploadPreparedContract")">
    @Html.Hidden("userApplicationId", Model.UserApplicationId)
    <div class="upload-section k-content">
        @Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("files")
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        currentDisclosedRate: "@Model.CurrentDisclosedRate",            
        changeRate: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var self = this;

            var rawValue = $('#newDisclosureRate').val();
            var rate = parseFloat(rawValue);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'ChangeDisclosureRate',
                data: { newRate: rate, userApplicationId: @Model.UserApplicationId},
            }).done(function(result) {
                Notification.success('Rate changed');
                self.set("currentDisclosedRate", rawValue);
            })
            .fail(function(err) {
                Notification.error('Not changed. Customer may have placed order');
            });                
        },
    });

    kendo.bind($("#page"), viewModel);
});
```

and here is the controller

```
public class ContractPreparationController : Controller
{
   // GET: Application/ContractPreparation
    public ActionResult Index(int userApplicationId)
    {
        // logic to prepare model    
        return View(new ContractPreparationOutputModel()
        {
           // Model properties
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ChangeDisclosureRate(decimal newRate, int userApplicationId)
    {
        return await Command.ApplyAsync(new ChangeDisclosureRateCommand() {UserApplicationId = userApplicationId, NewDisclosureRate = BasisPoint.Percent(newRate) }) == Command.CommandResult.Succeeded
            ? new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            : new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UploadPreparedContract(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, int userApplicationId)
    {
        if (files == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        if (files.Count() != 1)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "You must upload one file only");
        var application = applicationRepository.GetUserApplication(userApplicationId);
        if (application == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid user");

        var file = files.Single();
        var memberDocument = new  MemberDocument(blobService, application.FK_UserId);
        await memberDocument.Uploadfile(file);

        if (await Command.ApplyAsync(new UploadPreparedContractCommand() {FileGuid = memberDocument.FileGuid , UserApplicationId = userApplicationId, FileExtension = memberDocument.FileExtension}) == Command.CommandResult.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new {userApplicationId});
        }
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError); // No expected failure case
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Url.Action` helper method to generate the correct relative url to the action method.

```
url: '@Url.Action("ChangeDisclosureRate","ContractPreparation")',
```

When razor executes the code for your view, it will run the `Url.Action` method and output the correct url (which will have the controller name if needed). You can see it if you do view source of the page.

Comment: @Shyju.. why we need to mention @url.Action("") in ajax request. What is the logic behind this can u explain

Comment: Url.Action helper method returns the correct relative path (based on the route definition) to the specified action method. It is safer to use this method than hardcoding in your js code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the controller name to your ajax url parameter:

```
url: 'ContractPreparation/ChangeDisclosureRate'
```

Otherwise MVC doesn't know what controller to use.

Comment: I tried this. If I do this it will work for the case I described above but it will cause issue if I had not done any file upload. it will try to post to 'ContractPreparation/ContractPreparation/ChangeDisclosureRate' :(